# Loop through same query 2 times through 2 nested loops

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am not able to loop through the same query twice as follow, what am I missing?

```
$query = "SELECT ..."
while ($a = tep_db_fetch_array($query)) {
     while ($a2 = tep_db_fetch_array($query)) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Thus my question, how to loop through the same query two times one inside the other?

Comment: I think it's more a case of what you are trying to achieve by this.

Comment: @NigelRen I want to loop through all the results, and for each result's id I want to see if there are any other data with the same id to do stuff with them

Comment: Are you getting any kind of notice, warning, or error?

Comment: @DavidPartyka no, after the second while it does not go back to the first, as if the $query has been fully went through in both.

Comment: Can you even loop through once? Is it a version or environment problem?

Comment: Usually it is achieved by `GROUP`.

Comment: @DavidPartyka yes, I can, it's not an environment problem.

Comment: This sounds like you need a JOIN, not two loops. If you can post the structure of your tables and what you want to do, we can help a lot more. Nested loops over the same data definitely isn't the right answer.

Comment: you cannot loop over the result like this.  if you really nead to loop over the dataset in nested loops (although this seems to be a bad idea) you have to clone `$query` and loop over `$query` on the main loop and on the copy in the nested loop

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ thanks, that's the reply I wanted :)

Comment: @iainn thank you for your help, I suppose I won't do it this way then, but the question was simply if it is possible to do it this way, not how to do it in another way. As I have no found an answer to my question anywhere ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you know the data is not going to be excessively huge, then you can use **get_records_sql()** instead. This will return an array, indexed by the first field in the SELECT. You can then do what you want with this array (loop through it multiple times, split, pop, shift, etc)

Comment: What is `get_records_sql`? Form what cms/cmf?

Comment: get_records_sql() is function